# Taking more than a day to update 4500 Database rows

Tags: java, database, hibernate, entity

I want to append a new entry in a column in database using `java hibernate`. Below is the code snippet.

```
Collection<ContentEntity> contentList = null;
        contentList = new ArrayList<ContentEntity>();
        Long id=institutionSubscriptionEntityManager
                .insertEntity(institutionSubscriptionEntity);
contentList.addAll(contentEntityManager.findContentAllByPublisherAndStatus(publisher, "LIVE"));
        Iterator<ContentEntity> iter=contentList.iterator();
        if(null !=contentList && contentList.size()>0){
            while(iter.hasNext()){
                ContentEntity contentEntity=new ContentEntity();
                contentEntity=iter.next();
                String subscriptionId=contentEntity.getSubscriptionId();
                subscriptionId=subscriptionId+", "+id;
                contentEntity.setSubscriptionId(subscriptionId);
                contentEntityManager.updateEntity(contentEntity);
            }

        }
```

But it's taking more than a day to update just 4554 rows. Please suggest faster way.

Comment: Why not stick logging statements which print time stamps for you to identify which part is taking longest? For all we know, `contentEntityManager.findContentAllByPublisherAndStatus...` is hanging up the entire operation. Also, how are you calling this code? Do you do one bulk operation or do you call it repeatadly? As is there is  no way we can tell what is wrong with that code.

Comment: @npinti this is bulk operation, it returns all rows having `LIVE` status. I also debug the code `contentEntityManager.findContentAllByPublisherAndStatus...` never takes more than a minute.

Comment: Then I'd recommend you ask a new question which shows time values of how long do method calls take, and how is this being called.